# Instantiate an extended class from an instance of parent class - Typescript

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance, prototype, instance

I use a library that I want to extend in Typescript. This library has a class that I extend:

```typescript
import lib from 'lib'

class MyClass extends lib.ItsClass {

}
```

The library has also a function that returns an instance of its class. I want to create and instance of my class from that instance.

```
const its_instance:lib.ItsClass = lib.returnInstance();

const myclass:MyClass = ...
```

How can I convert `its_instance` in an instance of `MyClass`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the base class is using the [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). This a way to ensure that there is only ever one instance of the class.

Here's a basic summary of how that typically works. The constructor is made `private` so that instances cannot be created by calling `new`, except within the class.  The one and only instance of the class is stored to a `private static` property with a name like `instance`.  When you call the `public static method returnInstance()`, it checks whether the `instance` property has been set.  If not, it calls `new` to create the instance and then saves it to the variable before returning it.

Singletons are not really designed to be extended.  It's likely that this class is using `private` methods and properties, though in Javascript `private` is more of a suggestion than a rule.

The other issue is that there is only ever supposed to be one instance, but now you have two versions which are not entirely compatible.  If the base method calls `returnInstance()` first and sets the instance to a base class, then that creates a problem for your extended class.

One way around this would be to store the instance of your extended class under a different property name and have two separate instances, but now your instance and the base instance are detached from each other and have separate states.

Ultimately the cleanest way to do this is by wrapping the class rather than extending it.  Your class internally stores a reference to the base class instance (or it could just call LibClass.getInstance() each time).  It mimics the methods of the base class, but delegates the actually execution to the base instance.

Because typescript classes are also interfaces, we can say that `MyClass implements LibClass`.  This means that `MyClass` should be able to be used wherever `LibClass` is, but that we have to implement its methods and properties ourselves.

```
class MyClass implements LibClass {

    // our class will be a singleton too
    private static _thisInstance: MyClass | undefined;

    // not static, our instance will "own" the base instance
    private _baseInstance: LibClass;

    private constructor() {
        this._baseInstance = LibClass.returnInstance();
    }

    public static returnInstance(): MyClass {
        if ( ! MyClass._thisInstance ) {
            MyClass._thisInstance = new MyClass();
        }
        return MyClass._thisInstance;
    }

    public method1(): number {
        return this._baseInstance.method1();
    }

    public method2(): string {
        return this._baseInstance.method2();
    }

    public myMethod(): number {
        return this.method1() * 2;
    }
}
```

```
class LibClass {
    private static _instance: LibClass | undefined;

    private constructor() {

    }

    public static returnInstance(): LibClass {
        if ( ! LibClass._instance ) {
            LibClass._instance = new LibClass();
        }
        return LibClass._instance;
    }

    public method1(): number {
        return 5;
    }

    public method2(): string {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/8w82Am)

Comment: Actually it is not a singleton it is just a function that return an instance or an array of instances. At the end I used a reference of the instance of the parent class inside my instance of child class. As you also suggested.